# Given a block device file, how can I list all relevant partions?

Tags: shell, devices, block-device

**Given a device file *(ex: `/dev/sda`)* how can I get a list of all relevant partitions?**

Expected input:

```
/dev/sda
```

Expected output:

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
...
```

I know there are many ways to get information about block devices, such as `lsblk`, `blockdev`, `fdisk`, and `blkid` to name a few, but I want a solution that is the most succinct (ie, doesn't use an enormous number of pipes to `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `uniq` etc).

**What is the most condensed one liner to solve this problem?**

**Notes:** I'm using linux (specifically ubuntu) and using either terminal or shell script to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ls`:

```
$ ls -1 /dev/sda?*
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
```

Or, with `lsblk` (which is LVM-aware):

```
$ lsblk -lpo NAME /dev/sda
NAME
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/mapper/home-root
/dev/mapper/home-swap_1
```